# Inheriting second-level base class constructor: silent error

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, constructor

I ran into a very nasty error today, here is a MWE:

```
#include <iostream>

class X {

public: 
  X() { std::cout << "Default" << std::endl; }
  X(int a) { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
};

class Y : public X { };

class Z : public Y {
  using X::X;
};

int main() {
  Z instance{3};
}
```

Contrary to my expectations, "`Default`" gets printed. *Admittedly, the code is faulty because the inherited constructors of `Z` try to initialize `X` without specifying how to construct `Y`[(∗)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197106/calling-a-second-level-base-class-constructor).* But still, shouldn't the compiler complain? What's the rationale behind the default constructor of `Y` (and subsequently `X`) getting called, completely silently ignoring my parameter of `3`? Is this documented somewhere in the standard? Or is it a bug in my compiler?

My environment is `gcc version 6.2.1 20160916 (Red Hat 6.2.1-2)`. No compiler warning is produced even with `-Weffc++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: The question you link to is about C# not C++.

Comment: I think the construction logic remains the same, `Y` can not stay undefined, and constructs `X` on its way. But it shouldn't accept a parameter its own constructor doesn't have.

Comment: @ future readers: this was a confirmed bug in G++ that's fixed in recent versions. As such, this question is about behaviour that can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a g++ bug, the code is invalid. Only constructors from direct bases can be inherited:

> **[namespace.udecl]** §3 If such a *using-declaration* names a constructor, the *nested-name-specifier* shall name a direct base class of the class being defined

Comment: Thanks for the citation! I'll see if I can report it then or if someone has already.